# How to target and remove multiple sections out of a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Using VBA or A Standard formula, I need to edit the following from cells.

I need to remove everything up to and including "Path:",
Then I need it to find | and start over until it reaches the end of the Cell

**Example:**
Category Name: Ladies, Category Path: Ladies|Category Name: Sale, Category Path: Sale|Category Name: New, Category Path: New|

**Goal:**
Ladies|Sale|New

It can include NO "|" or it can include up to 20 "|"

Edit: Realized I needed to show my work AFTER the tour. :)

I have spent a day or two on this and so far this is only I can come up with...

```
Dim s As String
s = Range("Z7").Value

Dim indexOfPath As Integer
Dim indexOfPipe As Integer
Dim indexOfCat As Integer

indexOfPath = InStr(1, s, "Path:")
indexOfPipe = InStr(1, s, "|")

Dim finalString As String
Dim pipeString As String
finalString = Right(s, Len(s) - indexOfPath - 5)

indexOfCat = InStr(1, finalString, "Path:")

pipeString = Right(finalString, Len(finalString) - indexOfCat - 5)

Range("A47").Value = finalString
Range("A48").Value = pipeString
```

How ever I have got to the point where I am not confusing myself...

Comment: Split the cell value on "|", then split each value in the resulting array on "Path:" and take the second element from the result of that.

Comment: Any tips on accomplishing that?...  I will go looking now, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Function:

```
Function splitonbar(rng As Range) As String
    Dim tempArr() As String
    Dim temp As String
    Dim i As Integer

    tempArr = Split(rng.Value, "|")
    For i = LBound(tempArr) To UBound(tempArr)
        If Len(tempArr(i)) > 0 Then
            temp = temp & "|" & Trim(Mid(tempArr(i), InStr(tempArr(i), "Path:") + 5))
        End If
    Next i

    splitonbar = Mid(temp, 2)

End Function
```

It can be used as Formula on the sheet, or be called from another sub.  To use as a UDF put in a module in the workbook then simply call it with a formula:

```
=splitonbar(Z7)
```

Or you can call it with a sub like this:

```
Sub splitstring()
   Dim t as string
   t = splitonbar(range("Z7"))
   debug.print t
end sub
```

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY - Thanks, now that is see the answer, I can understand how it works... Thanks again!

Comment: @DavidMoreau please choose one of the answers to mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click on the green check mark by the answer you choose.  Unfortunately only one can be selected.

Comment: Thanks, picked this one because it was the first one I understood and got working, but everyone was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Split the cell value on "|", then split each value in the resulting array on "Path:" and take the second element from the result of that.

Like this:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim s As String, arr, v, arr2
    s = "Category Name: Ladies, Category Path: Ladies|Category Name:" & _
        " Sale, Category Path: Sale|Category Name: New, Category Path: New|"

    arr = Split(s, "|")
    For Each v In arr
        v = Trim(v)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            arr2 = Split(v, "Path:")
            If UBound(arr2) > 0 Then Debug.Print arr2(1)
        End If

    Next v


End Sub
```

Comment: you know people who down vote answers without explanation really frustrate me.  At least give us the chance to fix what is bugging them.

Answer (score 0):

To directly fit your needs:

```
Public Function test(ByVal arg As Variant) As String
  Dim i As Long
  arg = Split(arg, "Category Name: ")
  For i = 1 To UBound(arg)
    arg(i) = Left(arg(i), InStr(arg(i), ",") - 1)
  Next
  test = Mid(Join(arg, "|"), 2)
End Function
```

The `Split` itself cuts everything in front of the keyword. The `Left` cuts everything after the comma (including the comma itself)

If you still have questons left, just ask :)